# iOS - UIImageView Animation receiving memory warning

Tags: ios, animation, memory, uiimageview, memory-leaks

I am attempting to run two UImageViews that have multiple arrays of animations they load and animate based on a selection the user makes. For example, here is one method:

```
-(void)initiateAnimations {

nullAnimation = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0002" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0003" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0004" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0005" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0006" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0007" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0008" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0009" ofType:@"png"]],
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"null0010" ofType:@"png"]], nil];
}
```

And here is an `IBAction` calling the animation method:

```
-(IBAction)nullani {
player.animationImages = nullAnimation;
player.animationDuration = 0.50;
player.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[player startAnimating];
}
```

It all works well at first, but keep in mind i have about 5-6 other arrays of animations roughly with the same size images. They arent huge, ranging from 12-80k .png files. When i attempt to animate after a few times, I am recieving this error in the output:

`2013-03-16 01:34:44.438 [3316:907] Received memory warning.`

After i receive this message, any new animation loaded will crash the app.
I ran it through Instruments and was unable to find any leaks, and the output gives me nothing upon crash.

Is there any memory issues here? how can i get rid of this issue? thanks.

Comment: How big are the images?  Not size in kb on the disk, as .png files.  In pixels?  Remember that to display the images, they need to be decompressed, so it's probably not so much about the 12-80k size.  Are these full-screen images?

Comment: Remember that leaking memory isn't the only way you can run out of memory. You can just be using too much. What does instruments tell you about your memory usage? How many bytes are you using each time you kick off an animation?

Comment: @Nate normal size is 800x800, retina 1600x1600. Most of it is blank, lots of alpha with the main content being around 75x400 because i have animations that grow/shrink/extend around. the 800x800 acts as a stage.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually a lot of memory.  Again, it's not compressed size.  It's decompressed size.  Having blank space means the image can be compressed heavily, but it doesn't help when it's decompressed much.  This may just be a situation where you're using a lot of memory.  Do you need to keep all 5-6 arrays at all times?  Can you unload/reload some of them?  Obviously, you'll sacrifice speed, when you need them again.  But, you might not have a choice.

Comment: I'll also add that I built an app once that relied on this kind of `animationImages` animation, and I was disappointed at how few images I could keep.  It's so easy to code up an animation this way, but it may not be very efficient.  Is there a large part of the images that's the same for all frames?  For example, if the individual frames just show a bouncing ball, in a different location, on a solid background, then using this technique is probably not going to be acceptable.

Comment: @Nate i mainly am using .png because i need the transparent background. if i re exported all the images (ugh.. lots of time there) to GIF or something smaller that still can hold transparency, do you think ill still run into these memory problems? comparison 4-8kb files instead of 24-80kb files?

Comment: I don't think you're hearing what I'm saying.  You are **not** suffering from compressed file size.  It's the size of your image, once it's been decompressed by iOS.  That's more a function of its size in pixels, width x height.

Comment: @Nate and no, unfortunately this technique is the only one that works as of right now. and i get what youre saying now. bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1) Never have more than 1 animation loaded into an array. Once you stop one animation, and are ready to start another, delete the first animation and replace the image the viewer sees with the single image that should be showing. If you can determine the exact image that was showing (and am doubtful of this) then you can replace the array with a single image and the image will not flicker.

2) If you cannot do 1), then try using Core Animation directly (more work for you), and do the animation yourself. This gives you more control over memory usage (you could cache image bitmaps on the file system).

3) Using a Mac and AVFoundation or QTKit, make an animation from images, then create a "movie" that you start and stop instead of the image sequence. In this case you'd replace the static images in the bundle with movie objects.

Comment: please mr @nworksdev .. you don't have accepted yet.. any of "stackoverflow's" answers.. :(